# NuGet package restore - "Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio Options dialog"

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to use NuGet package restore from the command line on a build server.

```
nuget install myapp/packages.config
```

However, I get the following error message:

*Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio Options dialog.*

How am I supposed to do that without installing VS2010 *on* the build server? (no, I'm not doing that). Is there a registry setting or something? How is NuGet determining that package restore is disabled. Indeed, why is this something that they would even care about making disabled by default?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is currently happening because NuGet Package Restore needs consent before downloading packages and with the current way things work, there's no way to discern a user calling "nuget.exe install packages.config" from package restore.
more details on consent here : http://blog.nuget.org/20120518/package-restore-and-consent.html

note: this issue *should* be fixed next week.

As a workaround, you can give consent by setting the EnableNuGetPackageRestore environment variable to true.

Comment: For some reason running `set EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true` in command line (Windows 7) didn't work but setting the environment variable in Control panel -> Advanced system settings did. And those wondering which value is "true" in context of environment variables, for me `1` and `true` worked.

Comment: @EmperorOrionii Did you do this on your build server?

Comment: @MikeMarks ??? Yes, no, maybe, doesn't apply. I have no build server, a project is a hobby.

Comment: @EmperorOrionii Okay, understand.. I guess in your context, the build server is your local machine. :)

Answer (score 28):

Another way is adding

```
<packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
</packageRestore>
```

to file %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config.

Comment: I had package restore enabled in my Tools > Options > NuGet PM settings but was still getting the error in one solution. I added these lines (under the root configuration element) and it solved the problem.

Comment: If your configuration is empty (e.g.: <configuration/>), you should add the ending tag, so that it becomes:
<configuration><packageRestore>...</packageRestore></configuration>

Answer (score 1):

I've got one today.

Had the options checked in Visual studio 2013 but still got the error message.
Workaround to set environment variable worked, you should restart visual studio after adding the environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Check updating NuGet if you are using an old version of Visual Studio. That worked for me.

Comment: Yes, you'll note that the question was asked back in 2012.